# When does sign(E X_t) equal sign(E f(X_t))?

Tags: probability

**Setup**:  Let $X_t$ denote a random variable with support on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f$ denote some function (not necessarily continuous or differentiable).

**Question**: What are the necessary conditions that must be placed on $f$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\textrm{sign}(\mathbb{E} X_t) = \textrm{sign}(\mathbb{E} f(X_t))  \: ?
\end{equation}

Directions to any references/proofs on this question would also be greatly appreciated.

**Motivation**: Personally, my first thought on this as to see if I could apply Jensen's inequality in some clever way, but I got very little traction down that avenue. As it stands I'm stumped at how to proceed.

Comment: If one is looking for functions $f$ such that, for every random variable $X$, $E[X]\gt0$ implies $E[f(X)]\gt0$ and $E[X]\lt0$ implies $E[f(X)]\lt0$, then I suspect $f$ must be linear (increasing).

Comment: @Did That is helpful - thanks for the response.